# Problem with projection in meters with ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system

I hope you can help with the following problem.
I have a shapefile and want to project it using a projected coordinate system with meters as unit. What I did was to change the projection from ArcCatalog and then importing the shapefile into ArcMap. But when I do this, there are two problems:

1. Distances are completely wrong. By using the Measure tool, houndreds of kilometers are measured as less than a meter!
2. The numbers on the bottom-right which indicated the position and the units of the map are also wrong. When displayed in Decimal Degrees, are either 0 or 1. When I change this in meters, numbers are still very small.

The problem persists even after the projection is added to the dataframe. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help and suggestion.

Comment: "What I did was to change the projection" - how? Did you Define a new projection or actually Project the data?

Comment: you can't just change the projection in catalog. you have to export it to a new file (making some assumptions for lack of info) while defining the projection you want it to go to. change it back and start over.